# Convert single Unicode character to ASCII character

Tags: regex, python-3.x, unicode, type-conversion, ascii

I got a unicode e.g. "00C4" saved in an array. I want to replace a placeholder e.g. "\A25" in a text with the ascii value of an unicode from the array which only has the unicode value. I tried everything from encoding, decoding, raw strings, unicode strings and different setups with the escape symbol "\". The issue here is that i can not write the clear '\u1234' in the code, I have to use the array values and combine it with something like '\u'. This is my current code:

e.g. prototypeArray[i][1] = 00C4

e.g. prototypeArray[i][0] = A25

```
unicodeChar = u'\\u' + prototypeArray[i][1]
placeholder = '\\' + prototypeArray[i][0]
placeholder = u'' + placeholder
text = text.replace(placeholder,s)
```

Currently it is only replacing e.g. \A25 with \u00C4 in the text. The unicode character is not interpreted as such.

Comment: I think you mean "Unicode code point" instead of "Unicode". And ASCII is a subset of Unicode encodings. There is not always an ASCII value for a unicode code point. Which encoding scheme do you use for Unicode points above U+007F? UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have a unicode code point and want to convert it to the relating character. The unicode code points are only saved as number/string without \u in the array. I then want to add the \u in front of the number so that the character is interpreted as the actual character. The encoding is utf-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UTF-8 specific interpretation:**
I assume you have the unicode point represented in hexadecimal in UTF-8 stored as a string in a variable (c). And you want to determine the corresponding character. Then the following code snippet shows how to do it:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> cp2chr = lambda c: binascii.unhexlify(c.zfill(len(c) + (len(c) & 1))).decode('utf-8')
>>> cp2chr('C484')
'Ą'
```

**Explanation:** `zfill` prepends a zero if the number of characters is odd. `binascii.unhexlify` basically takes two characters each, interprets them as hexadecimal numbers and make them one byte. All those bytes are merged to a bytes array. Finally `str.decode('utf-8')` interprets those bytes as UTF-8 encoded data and returns it as string.

```
>>> cp2chr('00C4')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 1: unexpected end of data
```

Your provided example, however, is not valid UTF-8 data. See [Wikipedia's UTF-8 byte structure table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) to identify valid byte sequences. `C4` has bit structure `11000100`, is therefore a continuation byte and requires another character afterwards.

**Encoding independent interpretation:**
So you might be looking for interpretation of unicode points independent of the encoding. Then you are looking for the `raw_unicode_escape` encoding:

```
>>> cp2chr = lambda c: (b'\\u' + c.encode('ascii')).decode('raw_unicode_escape') 
>>> cp2chr('00C4')
'Ä'
```

**Explanation:** `raw_unicode_escape` convert the unicode escape sequences given in a byte string and returns it as string: `b'\\u00C4'.decode('raw_unicode_escape')` gives `Ä`. This is what python does internally if you write `\uSOMETHING` in your source code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. This is exactly what i was looking for.